# I need to send an image using "input type="file"" without any restriction on the image size

Tags: php, html, file-upload, bots, telegram

I'm programming a telegram bot.
I want to send an image to a series of IDs that are stored in my DB (I'M NOT UPLOADING A PHOTO I'M JUST SENDING IT).
The function to send the image works just fine.
The only problem I have is that images that are above 1MB size won't be sended.

I don't upload these images anywhere, I just send them specifying the image url (so it isn't a problem about a max size upload).

```
/*this is the function that I use to send the image*/


<?php

include "./db.php";
include "../Gestionale-Bar/webhook.php";

$queryID="SELECT DISTINCT acquirente FROM BackupChat ORDER BY acquirente";
$resultID=$conn->query($queryID);
$file =new CURLFile(realpath($_FILES["photo"]["tmp_name"]));
while($rowID = $resultID->fetch_assoc())
{
  $url        = $website . "/sendPhoto?chat_id=" . $rowID['acquirente'] ;
  $post_fields = array('chat_id'   => $rowID['acquirente'], 'photo'     => $file);

  $ch = curl_init(); 
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(
    "Content-Type:multipart/form-data"
  ));
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url); 
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1); 
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $post_fields); 
  $output = curl_exec($ch);
}

echo "<script language=\"Javascript\">
window.location.href='mywebpageblablabla';
</script>
";

?>
```

```
/*this is the input button where I select the photo*/


function img()
{
  var gridWrapper = document.querySelector('.content');
  gridWrapper.innerHTML =
    "<form action=\"inviaimg.php\" enctype=\"multipart/form-data\" method=\"post\" class=\"inputfile\">" +
    "<input type=\"file\" name=\"photo\"/>" +
    "<input type=\"submit\" value=\"send\" style=\"background-color:#2a2b30; color:#5c5edc; font-family:AvenirNext; width:10%; height:30px\"></form>"
}
```

Whenever I try to send an image that is under 1MB everything works fine.
So basically I expect to send photos with bigger size. :)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Change the maximum upload file size](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2184513/change-the-maximum-upload-file-size)

Answer (score 0):

in your **$post_fields** you have key **photo** which value is CURLFile object. In documentation of telegram bots it is written that it belongs pass a value which is *file_id as String to send a photo that exists on the Telegram servers*, *HTTP URL as a String for Telegram to get a photo from the Internet* or *upload a local photo by passing a file path*.

You wrote you didn't upload a file but just sending. Despite this you use a **$_FILES[]** to get a **realpath()** of file which is uploaded. Maybe this is a fault of *upload_max_filesize*. Checkout this.

Check also this this piece of code:

```
$file = realpath($_FILES["photo"]["tmp_name"]);
while($rowID = $resultID->fetch_assoc())
{
   $url        = $website . "/sendPhoto?chat_id=" . $rowID['acquirente'] ;
   $post_fields = array('chat_id'   => $rowID['acquirente'], 'photo'     => $file
);
```

Replace old one with this and give feedback. Greetings, plum!

Sources:

- **$_FILES[]** - https://www.php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.files.php
- **The CURLFile class** - https://www.php.net/curlfile
- **Telegram documentation** - https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#sendphoto

Comment: Hi,
and thanks for your  reply.
Unluckly this didn't fix the issue... actually, switching to this code didn't even allow me to send images anymore.

Thanks anyway :)